# Session Storage in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm having some difficulties with my current task. 
It happens that I'm building some HTML pages and I want to transfer data from one to another. I'm using "sessionStorage" for this, which works fine on Google Chrome, but not on Internet Explorer 11 or Edge.

When it's executed it's not recognized, and it says

> ...unable to get property 'setitem' of undefined or null reference

**Edit:** I share with you the code block where the error is thrown

```
    var _pnome = document.getElementById("nome1").value;
    var _pbday = document.getElementById("bday1").value;
    var _page = document.getElementById("age1").value;

    var _prof = document.getElementById("prof1");

    var _prof_selected = _prof.options[_prof.selectedIndex].text;



    sessionStorage.setItem("pname", _pnome); //The error is in this line
    sessionStorage.setItem("pbday", _pbday);
    sessionStorage.setItem("page", _page);
    sessionStorage.setItem("pprof", _prof_selected);
```

Comment: Could you please share with us the piece of code that's causing the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! :) To get high quality answers please make sure to follow these guideline: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask In this case it would a good idea to post the relevant code.

Comment: [sessionStorage is available in IE](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_window_sessionstorage). Without knowing more about how you're trying to use it it's not easy to say *why* you get this error.

Comment: it's not availaible in IE7 or earlier - and some corporates still use IE7!

Comment: @Bravo OP is asking for IE11

Comment: IE11 in compatibility mode? You'd be surprised how many IE11's I've seen in corporate environments running IE7 compatibility mode

Comment: Compatibility mode was the answer for me. Settings->Compatibility View Settings...

Answer (score 2):

How do you access the page? Local (file://) or Server (http://)?

I have created a sample using session storage, it works well on my side (using IE 11.116.18362.0 and Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0, running on the server). After researching, it seems that, if we access the page from locally, it will show this error. Please check it and access the web page from server.

Besides, if still not working, perhaps the issue is related to the browser setting, try to reset the browser setting: [reset IE browser setting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/17441/windows-internet-explorer-change-reset-settings) and [rest Edge browser setting](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/reset-microsoft-edge/).

Comment: I'm opening it locally. How do I open the pages on a server? Do I have to deploy it using IIS, for example?

Comment: @aRip try popping your code up on https://stackblitz.com/. It will generate a hosted example and you'll be able to share working code here.

Comment: @stwilz I just tried to work with this editor. The example is shown in a browser different than internet explorer

Comment: You could refer to the following article to deploy a Website on IIS：[How to Host a Website on IIS: Setup & Deploy Web Application](https://www.guru99.com/deploying-website-iis.html) and [ASP.NET Web Deployment using Visual Studio: Deploying to Test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis)